# composer requires laravel/framework 5.5.32 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.32]

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to update my composers on my server.
Locally, I managed to update my composers without any problems, but on my server when I run my command for update

```
composer update
```

this gives me the following error:

```
 Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.5.32 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.32].
- laracasts/generators dev-master requires illuminate/support ~6.0|~7.0|~8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.16, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.4, v8.0.0, ..., v8.28.1].
- Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v4.0.0, ..., v4.2.17, v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.16, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.4, v8.0.0, ..., v8.28.1], laravel/framework[v5.5.32]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
- Root composer.json requires laracasts/generators dev-master as 1.1.4 -> satisfiable by laracasts/generators[dev-master].
```

And here is my composer.json :

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.32",
    ...
    "spatie/laravel-newsletter": "^4.2.1",
    "spatie/laravel-cookie-consent": "2.11.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
    "laracasts/generators": "dev-master as 1.1.4",
    "backpack/generators": "^1.1",
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/Http/helpers.php"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  }
}
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear: `laracasts/generators` requires `illuminate/support: 6+`. How you managed to update locally is a mystery though

Comment: Why do you run `composer update` on a different server than your development machine? Never ever do that, especially when that server is the production system. Also, which parts of tht error message are unclear to you?

Comment: Also, requireing anything in `dev-master` (which, for `laracasts/generators`, means: requiring a commit from 2020) while also using some outdated packages like `laravel/framework` in v5.5.32 (released in January 2018, three years ago!) is pretty obviously breaking the chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your packages. Some packages require Laravel 5.5